# Foreach loop to import multiple dbases

Tags: loops, foreach, stata, dbf

I have multiple .dbf files that I would like to import one at a time, change the name of a variable, and save as a .dta file. The folder that contains the .dbf files contains other files as well that I would like Stata to ignore.

Each of the `dbf` files is named one of the options listed in the local macro `mylist`, followed by `_ward_CTS.dbf`. So for example, `B_ward_CTS.dbf` is one of the files.

My code is the following:

```
program drop _all
macro drop _all
set more off
cd "/Users/slums-india/cleaning/maps processing/Ward Point 
Maps/Output"
clear

local files : dir "/Users/slums-india/cleaning/maps processing/WardPoint 
Maps/Output" files "*.dbf"

local mylist B C D E FN FS GS HE HW KE

foreach file of local mylist  {

use 'file'_ward_CTS.dbf 

/*import database*/
import dbase "'file'_ward_CTS.dbf", clear

/*rename CTS number variable*/
rename cts$V4 cts_number

save "/Users/slums-india/cleaning/sra/temp/'file'_ward_CTS.dta", replace

}
```

I cannot seem to get this loop to run. The error I get is invalid 'file'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the first line in the loop, change `'` in `file` and add quotes:

```
foreach file of local mylist  {
    /*import database*/
    import dbase "`file'_ward_CTS.dbf", clear

    /*rename CTS number variable*/
    rename cts$V4 cts_number

    save "/Users/slums-india/cleaning/sra/temp/`file'_ward_CTS.dta", replace 
}
```

Comment: I just edited my code to include the top portion of it that already did include my working directory. I forgot to include that the error is invalid 'file'.

Comment: I just edited my answer. In the future please let us know the exact problem/error and where this is happening.

Comment: Now I am getting the error file 'file'_ward_CTS.dbf not found

Comment: Then the file is not in the directory. Or you use ' instead of ` in file. Copy my code and try again.

Comment: My code is the same. Do you think it has something to do with the mylist portion? Should I list out B_ward_CTS.dbf in mylist for each ward?

Comment: Sorry i just noticed that you are trying to use a dbf file! You need to import this not use it! The first line in the loop should be deleted.